# Can't open the react build with nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment

I try to open react app using Nginx. But there's an error which i can't solve.
Here is my script:

```
    server {
        listen        2864;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root "C:\react-app\build";
            index index.html;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
         
        }
    
        location /api{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }
```

And i have this error:

```
2021/05/25 09:28:56 [crit] 13908#13176: *7 GetFileAttributesEx() "C:
eact-app\build/index.html" failed (123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:2864"
```

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for Windows-Paths should be

`C:\\react-app\\build` or better `C:/react-app/build`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html